# help for gdb's stepi command

Tags: gdb, command

I  need to trace  all instrutions of  a program  using gdb.
After  every execution  of a instruction, I want gdb invokes a  specified function.

Is  it  a  possiable  work?  How  to achieve  this?

I searched internet and found  "stepi arg" command in gdb could step arg instructions.
But  how to find total number of instructions?
After every  instruction, how  to make gdb  to invoke my function automately?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use gdb for this? Is the function a gdb-function or a function in the program? I think if you specify an example of what you want to execute after each instruction and an example of a program that you want to execute, it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 3):

```
cat t.c
int main() { int x=1; int y=2; int z=x+y; printf("%d",z); return 0; }

gcc t.c
gdb -q ./a.out
break main
run
(no debugging symbols found)...
Breakpoint 1, 0x0000000000400488 in main ()
set logging on
while 1
 >stepi
 >info registers
end
quit
```

Now examine `gdb.log`: it should contain the info you are seeking.

P.S. This isn't a discussion forum. Please don't append questions as "answers". Instead edit your *original* question to clarify it, or use comments.

Answer (score 2):

GDB always prints "---Type to continue, or q to quit---" during execution because of the height or pagination parameter.

In order to avoid or disable this you have to give the following command either in gdb prompt or .gdbinit file

set height 0 or set pagination off